# How to have a generic variable to INumber in .NET 7?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0, .net-generic-math

We can use the new [`INumber<TSelf>` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1?view=net-7.0) in .NET 7 to reference any numeric type, like the following:

```cs
using System.Numerics;

INumber<int> myNumber = 72;
INumber<float> mySecondNumber = 93.63f;
```

However, because of the type constraint in `INumber`, we can't have a generic reference that can hold any numeric type. This following code is invalid:

```cs
using System.Numerics;

INumber myNumber = 72;
myNumber = 93.63f;
```

How can I have an array of any numeric objects and call a method that is expecting a `INumber<TSelf>` object.

```cs
using System.Numerics;

object[] numbers = new object[] { 1, 2.5, 5, 0x1001, 72 };

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} plus {1} equals {2}", numbers[i], numbers[i + 1], AddNumbers(numbers[i], numbers[i + 1]));
}

static T AddNumbers<T>(T left, T right) where T : INumber<T> => left + right;
```

Comment: We recently had questions where OP claimed that "DateTime - string" operation is well defined and makes sense... You seem to support that too... could you clarify why you expect some way to exist to make that working in strongly typed way? (Obviously you always could `(dynamic)numbers[i] + (dynamic)numbers[i + 1]` for compatible types... but that's reflection at runtime)

Comment: Note that even if it was possible it would result in boxing of value types to place them in collection.

Comment: @GuruStron my understanding is that the `INumber<int> myNumber = 72;` is already causing boxing. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias mine is too)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyAMABMugHQByArgLYCmATmAMYDOA3DsgMxGoEDCBAN44Coot2QAWAgFkAFAEohIsaoCSlKgCN6AHjAA7YAD4CVAJ6addAgF4CAdlTtsqgL443QA==) seems to agree)))

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: you can't.

---

You noticed that there's no non-generic type `INumber` which `INumber<TSelf>` implements, because this would cause havoc.

You know something bad is happening in your code when you have to declare

```
var numbers = new object[] { 1, 2.5, 5, 0x1001, 72 };
```

to hold your `INumber<T>` values.

You also couldn't declare, e.g. something like

```
var numbers = new INumber<>[] { 1, 2.5, 5, 0x1001, 72 };
```

because you'd encounter [CS7003](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs7003): "*Unexpected use of an unbound generic name*"

---

Suppose that there exists a non-generic interface type `INumber` which is a base type of `INumber<TSelf>` (in the same way that `IEnumerable` is a base type of `IEnumerable<T>`).

For `INumber` to be useful it'd have to have things like operators - but these would also have to be non-generic - so, for instance, a non-generic version of the [`IAdditionOperators<TSelf,TOther,TResult>` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.iadditionoperators-3) (which defines the `+` operator) would have to exist - it'd have to take `INumber, INumber` as its arguments.

Now, suppose you have a type, `UserDefinedNumber : INumber<UserDefinedNumber>` and you had

```
INumber a = 1d;
INumber b = new UserDefinedNumber(...);
var c = a + b;
```

Now - what would you expect `a + b` to do?

Since the left- and right-hand side of the operator are both typed as `INumber`, the compiler would use the implementation of the `+` operator on `a` (which is a `double`) but since that's a built-in type there's no way that it'd have any logic to handle adding a `double` to a `UserDefinedNumber`.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I have an array of any numeric objects and call a method that is expecting a INumber object.

The thing is that array must have all elements of the same type. Simply because array is just a memory block and i-th element is a place in memory located at address arrayStart + i*(elementSize). It just won’t work if sizes are different.

Therefore for value types it is not possible(they might have different sizes), but it is possible to have array of objects, then every element can have any type(will be boxed in case of value type).

So, you would need to create array of objects, where you can put float, int, whatever.

Also I don’t think it makes much sense to have common interface for all numbers, because if you you want to add float to long, how should you do that - cast to float or long? It is just much clearer to convert numbers to the most convenient type for the task.

Comment: Side note: km + hour may be much more obvious example than float+long

Comment: _"The thing is that array must have all elements of the same type."_ - this is the reason why working with value type via interface (without generics) results in boxing. So while you don't want that, technically it does not prevent to cramming different value types into the same collection of interface.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. The `INumber<TSelf>` type is declared like that:

```
public interface INumber<TSelf> : 
    IComparable, 
    IComparable<TSelf>, 
    IEquatable<TSelf>, 
    IParsable<TSelf>, 
    ISpanParsable<TSelf>,
    System.Numerics.IAdditionOperators<TSelf,TSelf,TSelf>,
    System.Numerics.IAdditiveIdentity<TSelf,TSelf>,
    System.Numerics.IComparisonOperators<TSelf,TSelf,bool>,
    System.Numerics.IDecrementOperators<TSelf>,
    System.Numerics.IDivisionOperators<TSelf,TSelf,TSelf>,
    System.Numerics.IEqualityOperators<TSelf,TSelf,bool>,
    System.Numerics.IIncrementOperators<TSelf>,
    System.Numerics.IModulusOperators<TSelf,TSelf,TSelf>, 
    System.Numerics.IMultiplicativeIdentity<TSelf,TSelf>, 
    System.Numerics.IMultiplyOperators<TSelf,TSelf,TSelf>, 
    System.Numerics.INumberBase<TSelf>,        
    System.Numerics.ISubtractionOperators<TSelf,TSelf,TSelf>, 
    System.Numerics.IUnaryNegationOperators<TSelf,TSelf>, 
    System.Numerics.IUnaryPlusOperators<TSelf,TSelf> 
    where TSelf : INumber<TSelf>
```

As you can see, all the interfaces use the `TSelf` type. So the `INumber` interface does not have a contract that supports operations between different types but only operations within the same type.

Since you have a list of mixed types, the compiler has no chance to check whether the actual types of operands at runtime are a supported combination.

Comment: Side note: I'm pretty sure restricting to `IAdditionOperators<TSelf,TSelf,TOther>` and using `dynamic` would let OP to call their AddElements method... but that is somewhat pointless as it was possible even before 7.

Comment: Well, using `dynamic` a lot is possible by exchanging compile time checks with runtime checks ;)

Comment: AFAIK CRTP is more of a convention rather then contract in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a generic method which will work on any two arbitrary number types using `Convert.ChangeType`, provided Convert knows how to deal with both:

```
public static class AnyNumberAdder
{
    public static T1 AddNumbers<T1, T2>(T1 left, T2 right)
        where T1 : INumberBase<T1> where T2:INumberBase<T2> =>
        left + (T1)Convert.ChangeType(right, typeof(T1));
}
```

With some modifications this can be made to work on enumerables as well.