# C# union/sum types and product/intersection types

Tags: c#, algebraic-data-types

Is there a way to simulate sum and product types in C#? What I basically want is a common base class and a bunch of marker interfaces for derived classes (sum type). Later I want to use fields of base class type but narrowed down to some subset using the marker interfaces (intersection type).

Here is a Typescript analogy for what I Want to do in C#:

```js
/*... common functionality in base class, doesn't fit interface */
abstract class Token { abstract readonly text: string; } 

// marker interfaces, _b and _u added just to simulate nominal type system,
// otherwsie TS would assume Binary === Unary
interface Binary { _b: number }
interface Unary  { _u: number }

class PlusToken  extends Token implements Unary, Binary { text = "+";   _b = 0; _u = 1; }
class MinusToken extends Token implements Unary, Binary { text = "-";   _b = 0; _u = 1; }
class MulToken   extends Token implements        Binary { text = "*";   _b = 0; }
class NotToken   extends Token implements Unary         { text = "!";   _u = 1; }

type BinaryOp = Token & Binary
type UnaryOp  = Token & Unary

let validPlus: BinaryOp = new PlusToken();
let validMul:  BinaryOp = new MulToken(); 
let validNot:  UnaryOp  = new NotToken(); 

// compiler guards against invalid case
let invalidNot: BinaryOp = new NotToken();
```

I have dug through the SO and internet already but what I have found so far are generally dated "no" answers. In recent years Java 17 got a bit of a support for that (with sealed records), has C# got any work done?

A follow up question: has there been work on this in C# in recent years or were there any related announcements (for example for algebraic data types support)?

Comment: See my related question: [C# Equivalent for C++ std::variant (sum type / discriminated-union)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74520239/c-sharp-equivalent-for-c-stdvariant-sum-type-discriminated-union).

Comment: [.NET 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/) supports [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math) using the [`INumber<TSelf>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1?view=net-7.0) interface.  You could make your interfaces generic and constrain using it, e.g. `public interface IBinary<TNumber> where TNumber : INumber<TNumber> { public TNumber BinaryNumber { get; set; } }`.

Comment: See [How to perform math operations with generic variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68736791/3744182) and [How to have a generic variable to INumber in .NET 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74496239).  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @dbc although the links you gave looked promising, they use interfaces, which are more limiting than a base class/record in my case. What I would ideally want is an `abstract record Base {}` and a `record Derived : Base`, each belonging to a range of possibly overlapping sets. The need for markers is when constructing objects to narrow down a set of possible values and pattern match later using the marker. What I can't do with that is use `Base` type and extract common code to base class without repetition. I can't see how to make it work on interfaces alone.

Comment: You can quite easily do a generic constraint on a function eg `DoBinaryOp<T>(T token) where T : Token, Binary` and now you could not call it wilth a `NotToken`